# Estimation of polarization perturbative term

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, many-body

I'm studying a diagrammatic approach to degenerate electron gas. Now I need to prove that the energy contribution, with an arbitrary potential, of polarization at first perturbative order given by the diagram:
[image: Diagramma]
is null. I expanded it as an integral:
$$
\Pi_{(1)b}^*(q)=\lim_{p^o\to 0^+}\lambda\int d^4k\int d^4p\text{ }(G^{(0)}(k))^2e^{ip^0\eta}G^{(0)}(p)U_0(k-p)G^{(0)}(k-q)
$$
$$
E^{(1)}_b\propto\int d^4q\text{ }U_0(q)\Pi^*_{(1)b}(q)
$$

I've made several tries, but I can't prove it. Have you got any ideas? Thanks in advance.